# UITableView datasource must return cell... don't understand why cell is nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am writing a simple application in the iOS and I am getting the "**UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:**" error.  I am trying to create some static row content.

`My view controller` is called `"StartViewController"`. In the .xib file I have 3 `UITableViewCell` `objects` called `"Section 0 Cell", "Section 1 Cell" and "Section 2 Cell"`. They are defined in the .h file as:

```
@interface StartViewController : UITableViewController
{
 UITableViewCell *cell0;
 UITableViewCell *cell1;
 UITableViewCell *cell2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell0;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell2;
```

In the .m they have been synthesized. I can't post a picture of my interface builder as I don't have reputation 10 yet.

The cells are populated like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"Processing section: %d, row: %d",[indexPath section], [indexPath row]);

if (cell0 == nil) 
  NSLog(@"cell0 is nil");

if (([indexPath section] == 0) && ([indexPath row] == 0))
  return cell0;

if (([indexPath section] == 1) && ([indexPath row] == 0))
  return cell1;

if (([indexPath section] == 2) && ([indexPath row] == 0))
  return cell2;

return cell0;
}
```

I know the problem is the cell0 is nil but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `nil` because you haven't set it up yet. Declaring and synthesizing an object doesn't allocate/initialize it for you.

You need to do something like:

```
if (cell0 == nil) {
    cell0 = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: doh! I have been caught out by that before, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ok, I have just done what you have said and, it does create an instance of a cell but its not the cell I have designed/created in the xib.  Its just a blank cell.  How do I tell it to use it? Do I not have to assign it the UITTableviewCell.  An analogy being I have declared an integer, now I have to assign the value to it. In this case I need to assign the designed UITableViewCell to it.

Comment: If you have made a cell in IB and linked it to your project, let's say it's called `customCell` then in the code above instead of `cell0 = ...` set `cell0` to use `customCell` You can also check out this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173584/custom-cell-from-nib-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Synthesizing a variable just generates the get/set methods for it, it doesn't actually do anything with the variable to initialize an object.  You'll still need to do that in your own code.  You actually don't even need variables for it at all, you can do something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if ( [indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        [[cell textLabel] setText] = @"Hi Mom";
    }
    if ( [indexPath section] == 1 && [indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        [[cell textLabel] setText] = @"Hi Dad";
    }
    //etc.
```